# How to correct URL for Tab Controller in Prestashop

Tags: controller, prestashop-1.7

While Clicking on Customers in Tab (Prestashop Backoffice admin), other Controller other than Customer is opening.

As in attached screenshot, it is redirecting to AdminZendesk while clicking on Customers. Kindly assist in resolving this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In prestashop 1.7 we can not change the menus graphically, so either you go into the database to modify the link that concerns you, or you follow this tutorial that will allow you to reactivate menu management in Backoffice.

https://www.h-hennes.fr/blog/2017/11/30/prestashop-1-7-gerer-les-menus-dans-ladministration/

Regards